# How to prevent compiler creating appname.resources.dll for a not more localized application?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, localization, culture

I have a winform application written with vb2010.

I changed the "Language" property of a winform of my application to  german, only for testing purpose. I built the application and in my \bin\debug folder it was created a new \de folder with the localized resource file "appname.resources.dll".

Then I set back the "Language" property to (Default) and "Localizable" to FALSE and built again the application, but the \de folder with its  appname.resources.dll were created again.
I have controlled each form in my application, the My Project setting too, nothing points to any other culture. I deleted the whole \debug folder, but after each build, I get always the \de subfolder.

I cannot understand what is changed in my application now: why does the compiler create a localized resource if I set back the form properties?

I repeated the same for a new culture (afrikaans), to discover any changes in the form properties: I found nothing that could help me, but now I get two subfolders.: \de and \af

Any suggestion? Thank you for replying.

**Edit: Solution found!**
In Solution Explorer, you have to click show all files; then under the form (or forms) there is a file named something like "formname.de-DE.resx", this is the languages resource file for the form "formname". You have to delete manually this file in order to build a non-localized project.

Answer (score 0):

Expand your form in solution area.

You find the file *yourformname.de.resx* delete this file and rebuild your project.

After using a localize language, vs create a resource file very fast. if you change anything on form or not!

To solve this problem remove wrong resource file.